# Remote Management (VNC-style) without Port Forwarding

Tags: remote-desktop, nat, port-forwarding, remote-access, vnc

Is there a way of setting up a VNC-style server (RDP would do as well) on machines behind NATs, and have access to them? Should be technically possible by having outgoing connections from the NATed terminals to a server, waiting for a remote user to access it.

We basically have a bunch of embedded devices at different clients, and we'd like to manage them remotely, without having to ask clients to set-up port forward for each terminal we install.

Comment: Have you considered something like LogMeIn? - https://secure.logmein.com/

Comment: Does it work through NATs? Will have a look, not free unfortunately but may be able to afford it.

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: Using it now. Awesome! If you want the points, post this again as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered something like [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com)? I use it for many of my clients.

Answer (score 0):

How would you propose to distinguish these servers behind the firewall? Only one VNC service can listen on a given port, there is no 'VNC Gateway' software available as far as I can find.

The only way to make this work without port forwarding would be to assign every machine with VNC a public IP address.

Comment: The NATed servers could just declare their identity (some ID/hash/key) to a central routing server, which they would connect to using OUTGOING connections. It's possible.

Comment: @HarryMexican sure, it's *possible*. That doesn't mean it exists.

Comment: turns out it does (see above). you've been SUPER helpful!

Comment: I guess if you like handing over infrastructure access to an unknown third party. Go for it.